# Searching users in Keycloak from Java code

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am using Spring Boot, Keycloak 10, java 8 and keycloak-admin-client jar. I am able to get user, his groups and roles.

When it comes to search I see different search method options for example I could :

```
 List<UserRepresentation> search = getKeycloakInstance().realm("my-realm").users()
                .search("username");
```

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/admin/client/resource/UsersResource.html

But what i need to do i to write couple of methods:

- search by roles (so search users who has some roles)
- search by groups and group attributes
- search by text (firstname, lastname, email) in 'contains' manner: *mytext*
- search by roles and text
- search by list of ids (uuids of users)

I dont' see such possibilities in keycloak-admin-client, or it is possible of what else should I use instead of keycloak-admin-client ?

Comment: You'll probably need to build up your custom code againt the keycloak API: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, keycloak-admin-client doesn't provide lots of search options.

How to find users by role:

```
RoleResource roleResource = getKeycloakInstance().realm("realm_name")
                          .roles().get("role_name");  
roleResource.getRoleUserMembers();
```

How to find all users in the group:

```
getKeycloakInstance().realm("realm_name").groups().group("your_group").members();
```

How to find users by username, firstName, lastName, email:

```
getKeycloakInstance().realm("my-realm").users()
            .search("username", "lastName", "email");
```

If it's okay for you, try to use [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) to get more search opportunities.

Comment: Thanks, what about searching by userIds ? As for groups and roles I will have to use couple of request to search users with thext, rols and groups at once. Rest API itself also does not provide such opprotunity as I see, so I will stay with admin-client jar.

Comment: I've just checked search implementation (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java). 
There is no way to search by multiple values of the attribute. You can search by only one id, name, role, and so on.
For example search by "lastName": search("lastName:mar", 0, 10) will return first 10 users whose last name contains "mar".

If you store some part of user data in your app DB and it's synchronized with keycloak DB, I would like to recommend you perform a search on your app DB to be more flexible.

Comment: I had a commercial experience working with Keycloak and I can't say I was impressed. 
We stored user data in Keycloak but decided to duplicate data in our app DB to be able to perform flexible user search. 
The bad thing about such an approach is that we need to synchronize user data in two DB.

Comment: @YuliiaZ What was the approach used to synchronize the users registered in the keycloak to the application database

Comment: @YuliiaZ what would you recommend as alternative for Keycloak?